# JavaServer Faces 2.0 requires Dynamic Web Module 2.5 or newer

Tags: eclipse, jsf, maven

I'm using Maven with WTP support in Eclipse. I've configured Project Facets to use Dynamic Web Module 3.0, Java 1.7 and JSF 2.1. Still I'm getting this error, under problems tab.
JavaServer Faces 2.0 requires Dynamic Web Module 2.5 or newer.
Could you guys point me in the right direction?

UPDATE:
Deleted the markers and the errors did not re-appear. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

when you remove the markers particular the JavaServer Faces 2.2 checkbox meaning it won't be selected or loaded in the IDE config.

I believe it will not use that particular component.